# Send text data via Bluetooth using React-Native App

Tags: react-native, arduino, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth (BLE) Module connected to an Arduino and I would like to send a simple text string to it using a React-Native app. Once the string is sent, the Arduino will do some processing.

I've tried using react-native-ble-plx but I've a feeling that isn't the right way to pass the text input to. I've tested using the Bluetooth Terminal Android app and was able to send text data to my Bluetooth Module/Arduino device. I basically want to replicate that.

In my react-native app, i'm able to connect to the Bluetooth Module but not able to send any data.

So, does anyone know which libraries I should be doing to send simple text data? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

react-native-ble-plx is far enough to do so. You can check out our side project which uses this lib to send colors to Arduino and handle LED lights https://github.com/SparingSoftware/HomeLed

Comment: I have a similar use case. I am exploring send data from an app built with react native through Bluetooth to FMC130. Any idea if this approach would work as well? https://teltonika-gps.com/product/fmc130/